# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'backend' when running script on Win7 machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywinauto

I'm trying to create a script using pywinauto to open various applications. I have code to open up Adobe Acrobat Reader and navigate to the 'Create a PDF' page. It works on 64-bit Windows 10, but not 64-bit Windows 7. When I try to run the script, I get

```
Traceback: <most recent call last>:
File "C:\Users\nick\Desktop\main.py", line 96, in <module>
acrobat_interaction()
File "C:\Users\nick\Desktop\main.py", line  68, in acrobat_interaction
app = Application(backend="uia").start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRD32.exe"), 
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'backend'
```

Here is my code:

```py
import time

from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop, findwindows
import pyautogui, subprocess, random

# get screen dimensions
width, height = pyautogui.size()


# Check to see if process exists, if so we can connect to the existing session
def process_exists(process_name):  # credit: ewerybody on StackOverflow
    call = 'TASKLIST', '/FI', 'imagename eq %s' % process_name
    # use buildin check_output right away
    output = subprocess.check_output(call).decode()
    # check in last line for process name
    last_line = output.strip().split('\r\n')[-1]
    # because Fail message could be translated
    return last_line.lower().startswith(process_name.lower())

def acrobat_interaction():
    # mouse movement
    pyautogui.moveTo(random.randrange(0, width), random.randrange(0, height), 2)

    # Start new process - link Application to Acrobat
    if process_exists("AcroRD32.exe"):
        print("Acrobat session already exists. Connecting...")
        app = Application(backend="uia").connect(
            path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRD32.exe")
        print("Connected to existing Acrobat session.")
    else:
        print("Acrobat process does not exist. Creating a new one...")
        app = Application(backend="uia").start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRD32.exe",
                                               timeout=20)
        time.sleep(2)
        app.connect(title='Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (32-bit)')
        print("Launched new Acrobat session.")
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: share more code, show the import. What is `Application`  ?

Comment: Edited with more code.

Comment: share the full stack trace as well. What is the name of the py src?

Comment: py src? not familiar. updated with stack trace

Comment: do you run the same versions of modules? OR Maybe for different Windows it uses different `Application` and version for `Window 7` doesn't have `backend` because it can't use different backends. Did you try without `backend` on `Windows 7`?

Comment: Please check if `comtypes` Python package is installed: `pip install comtypes`. Also check if `import comtypes.client as client; client.GetModule("UIAutomationCore.dll")` works without errors. If there is an error, please add it to the question. This DLL is required for registering `backend="uia"` in pywinauto. Default backend is "win32" and it always exists.